# Unable to clear pending transaction on current Nonce by increasing fees

Tags: ether, pending-transactions, nonce

I have a pending transaction from 1 week ago, I tried every step to clear it that I can find online.
I know which nonce it is, and I doubled and tripled the gas limit and fees, but it still won't clear.
Is there anything else that can be done?

Comment: The current implementations allow for tx replacement as long as the nonce is the same and that the gas price is at least 10% higher. Could you provide your original tx hash to see what has been received ? an additional hash of the replacement tx would be nice too.

Comment: Your tx (https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa58522451d634088d9a1a0ed48306f71c196a808c43266b6dc64ec34fb009911) has been replaced ( by this one https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0bdeda74c4902facfd0fef533e952482f10afc0719e34dc250d6fd5f31de7b44 )

Comment: hey i just fixed it, I had to increase all gas and limits and priority by 10x and it finally went thru...

Comment: Alright, yeah for a pre EIP-1559 you only need to bump gas price up, post EIP-1559 it's both gas fee and gas tip that needs to be bumbed up by 10% (equating to a total gas price 10% higher at least).